# RabbitMQ+SpringAMPQ: Receiving multiple queues in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, messagebroker

I am currently learning a bit about RabbitMQ + SpringAMQ and I was trying to make my SimpleMessageListenerContainer to be able to read messages delivered to my two queues, but only one is receiving it. If you have any further tips about the code or if there is any way of doing it in a better way please let me know It would be nice.

EDIT:
The issue is
**The code is not sending a message to both queues only to one.**

Basically I am receiving from two queues, one inserts something in the database the other one will receive a validation request. I wish later on to send a response to the routing key and exchange.

Here is my Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.DirectExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ChallengeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChallengeApplication.class, args);
    }

    static final String responseExchange = "response.exchange";
    static final String routingKey = "response.routing.key";
    static final String queueInsertion = "insertion.queue";
    static final String queueValidation = "validation.queue";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queueInsertion() {
        return new Queue(queueInsertion, true);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queueValidation() {
        return new Queue(queueValidation, true);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(responseExchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding bindingInsertion(@Qualifier("queueInsertion") Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueInsertion);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding queueValidation(@Qualifier("queueValidation") Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueValidation);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer containerValidation(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        container.setQueueNames(queueValidation, queueInsertion);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }


    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

}
```

As you can see my SimpleMessageListenerContainer has in the setQueueNames both queues I want to listen to. And my MessageListenerAdapter sends it to my Receiver.java to the method receiveMessage, another question would be how can I read from which queue I am receiving the message? It's possible this way or should I use the @RabbitListener in order to point it to each place?

Receiver.java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.axur.challenge.DAO.WhitelistDAO;
import com.axur.challenge.formatters.InputData;
import com.axur.challenge.model.Whitelist;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    @Autowired
    private WhitelistDAO whitelistDAO;

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        try {
            InputData inputData = new Gson().fromJson(message, InputData.class);
            String url = inputData.getUrl();
            if (url == null) {
                receivedInsertion(inputData);
            } else {
                receivedValidation(inputData);
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            System.out.println("It was not possible to read the input");
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void receivedInsertion(InputData inputData) {        
        Whitelist whitelist = new Whitelist();
        String client = inputData.getClient();

        if (client == null) {
            whitelist.setClient("global");
        } else {
            whitelist.setClient(inputData.getClient());
        }

        whitelist.setRegex(inputData.getRegex());

        System.out.println("Whitelist: " + whitelist);

        try {
            Whitelist selectedWhitelist = whitelistDAO.getSpecificWhitelist(whitelist.getClient(), whitelist.getRegex());
            System.out.println("selectedWhitelist: " + selectedWhitelist);
            if (selectedWhitelist == null || !selectedWhitelist.equals(whitelist)) {
                whitelistDAO.insertWhitelist(whitelist);
                System.out.println("Whitelist Added");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Already added before");
            }

        } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
            System.out.println("Whitelist NOT Added");
            System.err.println(dae);
        }

    }

    public void receivedValidation(InputData inputData) {
        //getting all regex from this client
        List<Whitelist> listWhitelist = whitelistDAO.getWhitelist(inputData.getClient(), inputData.getRegex());
        boolean match = false;
        //verify if the regex works for the url provided
        if (listWhitelist != null) {
            int index = 0;
            while (match == false && index < listWhitelist.size()) {
                match = checkRegex(listWhitelist.get(index).getRegex(), inputData.getUrl());
                index++;
            }
        }

        if (match == true) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    public boolean checkRegex(String regex, String url) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(url).find();
    }

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

}
```

And this is the Runner.java where I send the message to each queue to test it:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Receiver receiver;

    public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Sending message...");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ChallengeApplication.responseExchange, ChallengeApplication.queueInsertion, "{'client':null, 'regex':'[a-z]'}");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ChallengeApplication.responseExchange, ChallengeApplication.queueValidation, "{'client':null, 'regex':'[a-z]'}");
            //rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ChallengeApplication.responseExchange, ChallengeApplication.routingKey, "{'client':null, 'regex':'[a-z]'}");
            receiver.getLatch().await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: So, what is your question? The code looks OK if you want to do it this way. Of course, you can achieve the same using `@RabbitListener`. Therefore not clear what help is needed since it looks like you fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Also; if you use `@RabbitListener` you can add another parameter `@Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue` to see which queue the message came from; this is not possible with old adapter; you would have to receive the entire `Message`.

Comment: Artem, I am sorry, edited the question, I believe I was tired and forgot to explain the clear question, the issue is The code is not sending a message to both queues only to one and it's not clear for me why. And thanks Gary, I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, i think you should use the RabbitListner and passe the name of the queue as a paramter like this :

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitTopicConfig.QUEUE_NAME)
    public void consumerDefaultMessage(final Message message){
        LOGGER.info("Recive Message with default configuration {}", message.toString());
    }
```

Ans you should inject rabbitTemplate in the configuration class as a bean, in this case you can use many listner as queues exists :

```
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, it's not clear to me how to adapt it to my code, can you give me a more clear example in my case? I don't know what to maintain or hide from my code to make this work and I think I don't know which place should I put it. It's all in the Application.java?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot or do not want to use annotations you need to implement the `MessageListener` interface for your Receiver. Then you receive a `Message` object that contains additional metadata.

Here is an example:

```
static class Receiver implements MessageListener  {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {  {
        String routingKey = message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey()

    }
```

You register the Receiver via:

```
new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
```